# Issue in adding values to arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I need to add all the values from a web service into an array-list. I have done it by using the following code. But When I try to iterate through the array list, I am getting only the last element a number of times.

here is my block of code.

```
patStructure = new ArrayList<PatientListStructure>();
for (int j = 0; j < n2.getLength(); j++) {
    PatientListStructure tempPatStruct = new PatientListStructure();

    Element e1 = (Element) n2.item(j);
    tempPatStruct.setName(parser.getValue(e1, "Name"));
    tempPatStruct.setDOB(parser.getValue(e1, "Dob"));

    Log.i("pat_list1", "tempPatStruct.getName("+j+")>> "+tempPatStruct.getName());

    patStructure.add(tempPatStruct);
}               
Log.i("pat_list1", "parsingStr length>> "+patStructure.size());
for(int k = 0; k<patStructure.size();k++){
    Log.i("pat_list1", "k >> "+k);
    Log.i("pat_list1", "parsingStr.get(k)>> "+patStructure.get(k).getName());
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show the `PatientListStructure` class. My guess is that you've got static fields...

Comment: Can you include the length of n2 and the result of your logs in the second for loop?

Comment: Thank you very much, Jon Skeet. You were right. I changed that and it resolved the issue.

Comment: The fields in PatientListStructure (name, id, dob) should not be static. Declaring a field (inside a class) as static allows any instance of the class to access and modify that field. An instance variable (non static) has a separate value (and memory address) for each instance of the variable.

Comment: Your code is ok from.what we can see. Either you have static fields in your patient structure as mentioned OR your input has the same values in each `item`. The two combined would be, that your input has other static fields or overrides the previous values each time. The last one would be my guess. Could you check and add logging of the `item` ?